# Which google scholar citation format is IEEE standard?

Tags: publications, citations, citation-style, ieee, google-scholar

When I want to use formatted citation from google sholar it;s show 5 option to copy. Which one is IEEE standard? I add an image for clear my question.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None of the "standard" citations that they provide is IEEE format.

Instead, you should use one of the links at the bottom to take the format for your preferred citation manager, such as BibTeX, which can then be used to format following any publication venue's guidelines.

For IEEE in particular, the best option is generally BibTeX, because IEEE strongly pushes its authors towards preparing their publications via the IEEE LaTeX package and its accompanying BibTeX style format.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am writing my first paper in MS word that's why I faced this type of problem.

Comment: @Razik If you're working in Word, I believe that EndNote is the preferred format.  IEEE does support Word, but it's an awkward fit, and if you make the investment in LaTeX it will likely make your life easier in the long run.  If you're close to deadline right now, of course, it's probably better to stick with Word for this paper and start the switch later.

Answer (score 2):

Word supports the IEEE citation format already (at last Word 2016).

I would suggest using [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) to build a BibTeX-file to keep track of your references. JabRef can export to the reference list format Word supports (an XML-file). It can also directly import the BibTeX-entires downloaded from Google. I suggest this program, as the built-in reference list editor in Word is nearly useless. Another alternative, if you are on Windows, is to use [bibtex4word](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/index.html). This macro uses [MikTeX](http://miktex.org/) or [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) to generate a reference list from your BibTeX-file which is subsequently imported into your Word document.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggested that none of the options are in IEEE format, I first went looking for an online citation tool for this purpose. I found one which does not require any login or premium account: [Bibme](http://www.bibme.org/ieee). Another one is [Refme](https://www.refme.com/citation-generator/ieee/). Yet another: [Citation Machine](http://www.citationmachine.net/ieee-circuits-and-systems-magazine/cite-a-journal). You might also want to search for other tools, as they are in plenty on the Internet.